# Is it possible to pop an item from dictionary, which is a property?

Tags: python, oop, dictionary, properties

I have a little problem. I need to pop items from dictionary, but the dictionary is a property of a class.

```py
    @property
    def hand_scores(self):
        return {'Ones': YatzyHand.score_ones(self.hand), 'Twos': YatzyHand.score_twos(self.hand),
                'Threes': YatzyHand.score_threes(self.hand), 'Fours': YatzyHand.score_fours(self.hand),
                'Fives': YatzyHand.score_fives(self.hand), 'Sixes': YatzyHand.score_sixes(self.hand),
                'One Pair': YatzyHand.score_one_pair(self.hand),
                'Two pairs': YatzyHand.score_two_pairs(self.hand),
                'Three of a kind': YatzyHand.score_three_of_a_kind(self.hand),
                'Four of a kind': YatzyHand.score_four_of_a_kind(self.hand),
                'Yatzy': YatzyHand.score_yatzy(self.hand),
                'Low straight': YatzyHand.score_low_straight(self.hand),
                'High straight': YatzyHand.score_high_straight(self.hand),
                'Full house': YatzyHand.score_full_house(self.hand),
                'Chance': YatzyHand.score_chance(self.hand)}
```

I would like to be able to pop item for example in this way:

```
Player.pop('Chance')
```

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: The property just returns a dictionary. The fact that that originates from a property is irrelevant.

Comment: `thing.hand_scores.pop('Fives')`

Comment: Why not have this dict a variable of the class then just remove keys as you need? @juanpa.arrivillaga yes oops

Comment: Just implement a method called pop on your class, and have pop remove the item from its dict attribute, as needed. You'd (probably) want to have the dictionary saved as an attribute on the class, though. This is assuming its actually important to have a pop method on your class, which it probably isn't (pop is definitively a dictionary method, and unless your class is a dictionary, something more description like `removeScore` would make more sense)

Comment: @Jab Because, I will have to update the dictionary's values then and it will be hard.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Are you trying to remove the value from all future accesses to `hand_scores`? Are you trying to access the individual values?

Comment: Keep in mind that SO is not a tutorial site, but a QA, and there are some expectations for the quality and type of questions asked. You will probably be better served by asking this in, perhaps, python's official forum. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask has some information. In general, you will probably find your questions downvoted if they are in the vein of "how do I do X" without showing what isn't working for you, specifically, and increasing the quality.

Comment: @jirassimok I am trying to remove the value from all future accesses.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a local copy of the dictionary and modify that, but you can not modify the value in the function `hand_scores`, because it is created every time the property is accessed (because the function is called every time). If you want to be able to modify it, make it a normal instance variable instead.

Then, to make sure the variables are updated, you make the original dictionary hold functions that generate the values.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self._hand_scores = {
            'Ones': lambda: YatzyHand.score_ones(self.hand),
            'Twos': lambda: YatzyHand.score_twos(self.hand),
            ...
        }

    @property
    def hand_scores(self):
        "Generate the dictionary of hand scores"
        return {key: valuefn() for key, valuefn in self._hand_scores.items()}

    def pop_hand_score(self, key):
        "Remove a score from hand_scores, returning its current value"
        return self._hand_scores.pop(key)()
```

So the values in the dictionary are generated at each call, but the keys are kept in an instance variable. Then `pop_hand_score` can be used to remove a key from the instance, and return its last value.

Personally, I think having a dictionary of lambdas like that is fairly poor style, but it does work.

A slightly cleaner technique (in my opinion) that would also allow you to put keys back would be to just keep a set of keys in an instance variable, and the dictionary mapping them to functions could remain in the function.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self._hand_score_keys = {'Ones', 'Twos', ...}

    def hand_scores(self):
        # You could also make this a dict of actual values if you
        # don't mind calculating them even when you don't need them.
        score_functions = {
            'Ones': lambda: YatzyHand.score_ones(self.hand),
            'Twos': lambda: YatzyHand.score_twos(self.hand),
            ...
        }
        return {key: score_functions[key]() for key in self._hand_score_keys}

    def ignore_score(self, key):
        self._hand_score_keys.remove(key)

    def recall_hand_score(self, key): # needs a better name
        self._hand_score_keys.add(key)
```